# Help with event signup module

Tags: 6, users

I'm looking for a module that allows registered users to signup to events with a few options. I found the "Signup Module" but I can't figure out how to make it work, at least to try it out. So two questions:

1. Does the Signup Module allow for getting different input depending on the event type? For example, if an event is a dinner, I would need to get the menu choice and any dietary requirements.
2. If the above is a yes, how can I make it work? I can't find much documentation around and I'm still a Drupal newbie. If the above is no, can you please recommend a more adeguate module?

Thanks in advance for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the Signup Module for this. The Signup form itself can be modified and changed for your needs. Have a look at the file signup_form.inc in the signup/theme folder. Copy the theme_signup_user_form($variables) function to your template.php in your theme and start modifying the form.

Comment: Great, this seems like the way to go. The only problem is that I have to modify the file every time the event type changes, in order to present the correct fields. Any workarounds?

Comment: Do you have different Content Types which are allowed to signup or do you have one Content Type which you modify for an Event? Or what do you mean by "event type changes"?

Comment: Different event types require different fields. For example, a dinner event requires a "menu type" select box, while a talk event doesn't.

Comment: OK, but then you create different content types. Then you check on the form what content type the signup belongs to and modify the form output as needed.

Comment: Alright! One last thing: how do I check the content type?

Comment: You should find the node type in the $variables array. Check the comments of this function.

Answer (score 1):

- Install [Date](http://drupal.org/project/date) module
- Create a content type "event" and add a date field.
- Go to admin/structure/types/manage/your_content_type and in the
  SignUp settings select enabled and for the Date field to use with
  signup choose the one you have in your content type.
- The options in the menu admin/config/people/signup are pretty
  straightforward.
- Create some content for your event content type to see the behaviour
  of signup

That along with signup documentation should be enough to test the module.